# Log in to Facebook via JS without Facebook login button for testing(AWS Cognito)

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am writing a Lambda function in which I require AWS Cognito credentials to call certain methods. The AWS Cognito credentials are provided via Facebook Auth. Its pretty easy implementing a Facebook-Cognito auth flow on the client side thanks to the FB-JS-SDK and AWS-JS-SDK, but how can I do it in a test ? Since I can't interact with a popup using mocha and node.js. Is there anyway to test this auth-flow ?

Tanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a nice feature inside their SDK for [test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users) that might be what you're looking for.